# Game App using surfaceview in android

Tags: surfaceview

I m trying to develop a game app using surfaceview.The app runs properly but becomes slow in  between.I m stuck with this problem.Plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many possible problems, if you don't post any code we can't help

Answer (score 0):

The question is too generic.. Have you been using any resource that are not recycled? Also considered call unlockCanvasAndPost() / unlockCanvas() only once for each loop.